# Read from file and save in Property using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to read two values from a text file both values on a different line

for example:

1234 
 
5678

This is what I tried:

```
def f = new File('/testdata.txt') 
def records = f.readLines();

records.each {
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdOne",it)
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdTwo",it)

}
```

But it is only setting the last value to both custom properties.

Comment: Can you tell the use case? It may have different solutions based on how these values to be used later? Currently only have two values. What if you have more? Just wanted to understand what you are trying to achieve? Is it data-driven test which you like to do ?

Comment: in your loop you are doing 2 iterations and calling twice setPropertyValue with the same value of it. The second iteration overwrites the first. May be you meant to do: testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdOne",records[0]), testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdOne",records[1]) without a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your loop iterates two times, the first it assigns the first value to your `IdOne` and `IdTwo` properties, the second iteration overwrites both properties with the second value; due to this you've the last iteration value in your both properties. A possible solution as @user1708042 notes in the comments could be simply not iterate and set the values for your properties directly:

```
def f = new File('/testdata.txt') 
def records = f.readLines()
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdOne",records[0])     
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdOne",records[1])
```

Another possible solutions could be to combine two lists; one with the property names and other one with the values in a Map, and then iterate over map entries setting the property name and the property values, for example:

```
def propertyName = ['IdOne','IdTwo']
def records = ['1234','5678'] // def records = new File('/testdata.txt').readLines()

def mapProperties = [propertyName,records].transpose().collectEntries()

mapProperties.each{ name, value ->
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(name,value)     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is running for me but I want to take values from the text file and pass it array dynamically so that N number of values can be processed

**Given** - one text file with the list of numbers(User ID )  and each time the text value should be incremental.

Expected: each time one row from the text file should be fetched and stored it into the custom property at the project level so that I can run same test steps with distinct ID.

```
def f = new File('C:\\GroovyTEst.txt') 
def records = f.readLines()
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("VendorRideid",records[0]) // here the value should be dynamic so that i can read one by one values from the text file 

def tCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["ChangeRidestatus-accepted"]
def tStep = tCase.testSteps["Pending"]
    tStep.run(testRunner, context)
def tStep1 = tCase.testSteps["Change RideStatus - Accepted"]
    tStep1.run(testRunner, context)
```